# I'm going to do vs I'm going to have

Tags: grammar, differences

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this so please let me know if its not appropriate.

I was wondering if there's any general rule on when to use "have" and "do" in the sentence "I'm going to".
The closest thing I can think of is "I'm going to have (an event)" and "I'm going to do (an activity)" but I feel like the line between what can be considered an event and an activity is blurry.

E.g. "I'm going to have a party/basketball practice/a nap/dinner/a shower." and "I'm going to do homework/chores/the dishes/laundry."

Is it just a matter of learning it by memory?

Comment: I wouldn't speak of 'having' sports or music practice - I would use 'do' for practising on my own or 'going to' an organised practice session. You 'have' a meal, but you can also 'take' a nap or a shower and 'give' (or, strangely, 'throw') a party.

Comment: You can see from your examples there's a difference between where the two are used, but there's not a general rule, just lots of idioms like "have a party", "do the dishes". Consult a good dictionary of idioms if you're in doubt.

Comment: Often, thinking of the different senses 'have = put on = hold' [a party, an auction, a meeting ...) and 'have = partake of' [a shower, a stroll, lunch] can help. But a further complication is the overlapping delexical usage of 'take' with the second sense. // Overlap is sometimes possible: 'When we do an open-air concert' / 'When we have an open-air concert' (though even here, 'do' connotes more the performers, 'have' the organisers).

Comment: 'He'll have a fit' / 'He'll do his nut' / 'He'll throw a wobbler' / ... illustrate the vagaries of English.

Comment: [What is the difference between the verbs "make and "do"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/what-is-the-difference-between-the-verbs-make-and-do) and ["Take a degree" or "do a degree"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46667/) and ["Take a rest" or "have some rest"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52673/)

Comment: I wonder what your native language is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's any general rule on when to use "have" and "do" in the sentence "I'm going to".

First, let me say that there are no "rules" in English. Some things may look like a rule - they aren't.

The problem is "I'm going to". It is is a distraction. It does not have an effect of the choice of "have" and "do".

With "have", it is usually possible to omit it.

**1.** "I'm <s>going to have</s> **having** (an event)"

1. "To have" with an event is used as a causal verb, as in

"**I am having** my bedroom redesigned." = I am **making arrangements** / **arranging** for my bedroom to be redesigned.

I'm having a party = I am arranging a party.

2. To do "I am going to do the dishes." = "I am going to do **the washing of** the dishes." = I am going to/I plan **to wash** the dishes.

Here, "do" is a pro-verb: as a pronoun takes the place of a referenced noun, a pro-verb takes the place of an understood verb.